# Why doesn't LINQ SQL syntax respect nullability inference?

Tags: c#, linq, nullable

Consider these two methods:

```cs
IEnumerable<T> WhereNotNull<T>(IEnumerable<T?> seq) =>
  from item in seq
  select item;

IEnumerable<T> WhereNotNull2<T>(IEnumerable<T?> seq) =>
  seq.Select(item => item);
```

The first method, which uses the SQL LINQ syntax, does not raise any compiler warning, whereas the second, which uses method chaining, does: `Nullability of reference types in value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T?>' does not match target type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>'`

Why is the nullable type information lost in the first method?

Comment: What is the compiler error? You're sure that it isn't a warning?

Comment: CS8619 is indeed a warning, not an error

Comment: Yes, it's probably a warning, but we treat warnings as errors.

Answer (score 2):

> The compiler uses static analysis to determine the null-state of a variable. A variable is either not-null or maybe-null. The compiler determines that a variable is not-null in two ways:

> 1. The variable has been assigned a value that is known to be not null.
> 2. The variable has been checked against null and hasn't been modified since that check.
>    This is from [microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references)

So for the first function `WhereNotNull` the compiler doesn't find anything strange with the variable `seq` because it is not statically evaluated at this time. The code

```
  from item in seq
  select item;
```

will be converted further into fluent syntax `seq.Select(n=> n)`.

In the second example for `WhereNotNull2` the compiler can apply the Null-state analysis and detect a *maybe-null* situation and trigger the warning that `seq` may be null.

Comment: So it's a limitation of the null state analysis or a not yet supported feature. When is a LINQ-query translated to method syntax, at compile- or at run-time? [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/query-syntax-and-method-syntax-in-linq) suggests that it's a compiler feature, so it should be possible to make the null analysis afterwards.

Comment: Seconding that comment, I'd like to know if/why there's anything preventing static analysis, whether there are any inherent limitations or whether this is simply on the backlog of things to implement.